# Angular callback after observable next

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to be able to execute a call back after `Observable.next()` has been processed.

I have a component "A" that has a subject send notifications using `Subject.next()`.
I have a component "B" that has subscribed to `Subject.asObservable()` in order to perform code.

When A trigger next to B, I would like to perform some code once `Subject.next()` has been executed.

**Service**

```
 private submitSubject = new Subject<String>();
 private submitObservable = this.submitSubject.asObservable();
```

**Component A**

```
 public onClickSubmit():void {
      ....
      this.xxxxService.executeSubmit()
  }
```

**Component B**

```
ngOnInit() {
        // Subscribe to parent Submit button
        this.subscription = this.xxxService.getSubmitObservable().subscribe(value => {...} );
  }
```

I would like to be able to do something like

```
obervable.next().subscribe(e => {})
```

Comment: you can add many subscribers on the submitSubject by : this.xxxService.submitSubject.subscribe(value => {console.log(val)} ); 
and once you call obervable.next() subscription call back functions will be executed

Comment: Maybe I got the question wrong, but you can `pipe()` any operator to your Observable before subscribing, so any operation you want can be performed before you subscribe. Wouldn't this be easiest?

Comment: Was you able to find an answer to your question? Because all the answers below are useless for the matter. I am not sure, but it seems that respondents do not understand what was asked. :)

Answer (score 1):

In fact I saw only 2 solutions
- Having 2 sujects/obersvables : 1 for execution, 1 for result
- Having 1 subject/obersvable : using subject.next to notify and subject.complete to achieve, but in this case you have to re instantiate subject/obersvable for each execution.

**1) Solution 1**

Component A (parent) subscribes to resultNextSubject (on 'next' method)

Component B (child) subscribes to nextSubject (on 'next' method)

In Component A when you click on "Next" button it calls nextSubject.next to notify component B for submit (validation save)

Component B perfom submit and call **resultNextSubject.next()** to notify result to component A
Component A receive resultNext notification and route to another component for display
etc..

Component A (parent)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pi-xxx',
  providers: [xxxService],
  templateUrl: './xxx.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./xxx.component.scss']
})
export class xxxAComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private router: Router, private xxxService: XxxService) {}

  ngOnInit() {  
    ...    
      // Subscribe to child notification to navigate to a tab
      this.subscription = this.xxxService.getNextResultObservable().subscribe((value) => {
    ..routing..);
     }
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  public onClickNext(): void {
      ...
      this.xxxService.executeNext();
  }

}
```

Component B (child)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'pi-tab2',
  templateUrl: './tab2.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab2.component.scss']
})
export class Tab2Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    private subscription:Subscription;

    constructor(private xxxService:XxxService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        // Subscribe to parent Next button
        this.subscription = this.xxxService.getNextObservable().subscribe(value => {
            this.submit();
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    submit() {
      ...
      // Notify result to parent
      this.xxxService.getNextResultSubject().next();
    }

}
```

**2) Solution 2**

Component A (parent) subscribes to nextSubject (on 'complete' method)

Component B (child) subscribes to nextSubject (on 'next' method)

In Component A when you click on "Next" button it calls nextSubject.next to notify component B for submit (validation save)

Component B perfom submit and call **nextSubject.complete()** to notify result to component A

Component A receive resultNext (complete) notification and route to another component for display. But component A must do re instantiate subject and its oberservable before routing.

Component A

```
ngOnInit() {
  .... init
}

public onClickNext(): void {
      ....
          // Subscribe to wait for child result notification
          this.xxxService.nextObservable().subscribe({
              complete: () => {
                  // Must reset subject & observable before routing next child
                  this.xxxService.nextSubject =  new Subject();
                  this.xxxService.nextObservable = this.xxxService.nextSubject.AsObservable()
                  ....routing...
              }}
           );

          // Notify child
          this.xxxService.executeNext();
      }
  }
```

Component B

```
ngOnInit() {
            // Subscribe to parent Next button
            this.subscription = this.xxxService.getNextObservable().subscribe(value => {
                this.submit();
            });
        }

        ngOnDestroy(): void {
            this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        }

        submit() {
          ...
          // Notify result (complete) to parent
          this.xxxService.getNextSubject().complete();
        }
```

Comment: Too complicated solution for such an easy matter. But I was not able to find another so far. So, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So your almost there, all you have to do is subscribe to the `submitObservable` (so you need to make it `public`) which is updated when you call `next` on the `submitSubject` so a quick example is

**service**

```
 private submitSubject = new Subject<any>();
 public submitObservable = this.submitSubject.asObservable();

 executeSubmit(value) {
   this.submitSubject.next(value);
 }
```

**component A**

```
onClickSubmit() {
  this.service.executeSubmit();
}
```

**component B**

```
this.subscription = this.service.submitObservable
   .subscribe(result => {
     // do something
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just return subject as observable from service so `executeSubmit` can be subscribed

```
 this.xxxxService.executeSubmit=()=>{
       submitSubject.next(...)
       return this.submitSubject.asObservable()
 }
```

In your component you can do

```
 onClickSubmit() {
     return this.service.executeSubmit();
 }
```

Execution

```
 onClickSubmit().subscribe()
```

alternative you can use traditional call back

```
 onClickSubmit(cb) {
     this.service.executeSubmit();
     if(typeof cb==='function')
        cb()
 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it will work in my case, because the function cb() will be executed at any time and before the Obersable.next of the component B that performs submit actions (checks + REST call to store data).